# Standard error of estimated parameters with tensorflow.js

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js, exponential

I am using tensorflow.js to get the parameters of an exponential regression:

y(x) = c0*e^(kx)

I attach the code:

```
x = tf.tensor1d(x);
y = tf.tensor1d(y);
const c0 = tf.scalar().variable();
const k = tf.scalar(this.regression_parameters.array[index][0]).variable();
// y = c0*e^(k*x)
const fun = (x) => x.mul(k).exp().mul(c0);
const cost = (pred, label) => pred.sub(label).square().mean();
const learning_rate = 0.1;
const optimizer = tf.train.adagrad(learning_rate);
// Train the model.
for (let i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
optimizer.minimize(() => cost(fun(x), y));
}
```

which fits well the experimental signal. However, I need to report a standard error of the estimations (c0 and k), as it is given in SciPy by curve_fit(). I am wondering if this can be done with tensorflow.js. If not, is there any other JavaScript library that could be useful? Thanks!

Comment: I think that as it is, you cannot predict the standard error. Predicting an error on the variable supposes that the prediction is made along with an interval of confidence. There is no interval prediction here.

Comment: I see. I know SciPy curve_fit() gets the standard error by estimating them from the covariance matrix. I was hoping to be able to be able to do the nonlinear fit without using a Python server, but I cannot find any JavaScript library with a similar approach.  If anyone knows of any library available it would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested, I end up estimating the Hessian matrix of the exponential function myself to calculate the standard error of the parameters after tensorflow.js has optimised them. I followed the code on:
[https://www.cpp.edu/~pbsiegel/javascript/curvefitchi.html](https://www.cpp.edu/%7Epbsiegel/javascript/curvefitchi.html)

which is as follows:

```
function hess_exp_errors(c0, k, x, y){
 var sum1=0,sum2=0,sum3=0,sum4=0,sum5=0, expon1,
 he11, he12, he22, dett, dof, k_err, c0_error;
 for (i=0;i<x.length;i++){
  expon1=Math.exp(k*x[i]);
  sum1+=expon1*expon1;
  sum2+=y[i]*x[i]*x[i]*expon1;
  sum3+=x[i]*x[i]*expon1*expon1;
  sum4+=y[i]*x[i]*expon1;
  sum5+=x[i]*expon1*expon1;
 }
 he11=4*c0*c0*sum3-2*c0*sum2; he22=2*sum1;
 he12=4*c0*sum5-2*sum4; dett=he11*he22-he12*he12;
 c0_err=Math.sqrt(he11/dett); k_err=Math.sqrt(he22/dett);
 return [c0_err, k_err];
};
```